Connection timeout using the sock_connect method of the asyncio library
When I use the connect method of the socks library directly, the connection is successful, but when I replace it with the sock_connect method of the asynic library, the connection times out.
import asyncio
import socks
from _socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM


async def conn():
    parsed = (3, 'localhost', 7890, True, None, None)
    timeout = 10
    address = ('149.154.167.51', 443)

    sock = socks.socksocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.set_proxy(*parsed)
    sock.settimeout(timeout)

    # use sock_connect
    await asyncio.wait_for(
        asyncio.get_running_loop().sock_connect(sock=sock, address=address),
        timeout=timeout
    )

    # use socks.connect_ex
    status = sock.connect_ex(address)
    print('connect status: ', status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(conn())


when I use sock.connect_ex, I got:
connect status:  0
when I use sock_connect, I got:
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
I think this error is caused by connection timeout.
I debugged the code and found that sock_connect has two implementations, selector_events and proactor_events. My program uses proactor_events. Finally, the connect method in windos_events is used. I don't know if this affects the problem.

I want to connect to the telegram server locally, where localhost:7890 is my proxy address and 149.154.167.51 is the corresponding telegram server address
